# Sort or filter results by function query defined in a field

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a Solr 6.2 instance running, and I'm exploring its advantages and limitations. One limitation I've run into seems to be that you can't sort or filter the data based off of a field function query.

```
.../solr/collection/select?q=*:*&fl=*,total:sum(v1,v2)&fq=total:[10 TO *]
```

Solr responds with an error stating that the `total` field does not exist. Indeed, the field is not defined in my schema because it's not a stored part of the dataset - it's calculated at query time. They call it a pseudo field. I haven't been able to find an example in the documentation or a solution online. So, is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

```
.../solr/collection/select?q=*:*&fl=*,total:sum(v1,v2)&fq={!frange l=10} sum(v1,v2)
```

I have very same problem as you.
I want to query particular division value of two fields.

I tried to used `[0.3 TO *]` like you.

You can also use upper bound for your range if you need.

http://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/ref-guide/apache-solr-ref-guide-4.6.pdf

"**l**" is for lower bound.

"**u**" is for upper bound.

`fq={!frange l=0 u=2.2} sum(user_ranking,editor_ranking)`

Maybe this works for you?

Comment: The original asker confirmed in the comments below that one of the goals was to avoid having to retype the functions in multiple locations.

Answer (score -1):

you can do this. instead of total try sum.
you can find more info here. https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#What_is_a_Function.3F

an example from the sole wiki.

> **Example Function Queries**
>   To give you a better understanding of how function queries can be used in Solr, suppose an index stores the dimensions in meters x,y,z of some hypothetical boxes with arbitrary names stored in field boxname. Suppose we want to search for box matching name findbox but ranked according to volumes of boxes. The query parameters would be:
>   q=boxname:findbox *val*:"product(x,y,z)"
>
> This query will rank the results based on volumes. In order to get the computed volume, you will need to request the score, which will contain the resultant volume:
>   &fl=*, score
>
> Suppose that you also have a field storing the weight of the box as weight. To sort by the density of the box and return the value of the density in score, you would submit the following query:
>   http://localhost:8983/solr/collection_name/select?q=boxname:findbox *val*:"div(weight,product(x,y,z))"&fl=boxname x y z weight score`

you can read more about it here. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Function+Queries

Try this
`solr/collection/select?q=*:* _val_:"sum(v1,v2)"&fl=* score&fq={!frange l=10 }sum(v1,v2)`

Comment: That's what I'm doing. How can I filter on a pseudo field without retyping the same function again into a `fq` or `sort` parameter?

Comment: what does total:[10 TO *] in the fq menas ?

Comment: It's a range query. It says, return records whose `total` is equal to or greater than 10.

Comment: see the last line in the answer.

Comment: Right, but can I do it without repeating the `sum()` function more than once in the query? (see my edit to the question)

Comment: You may be able to use variable substitution. It uses [${var} syntax](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Parameter+Substitution).